# How to split a file using FileSplitter (@Splitter) in Spring Integration using java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to split my message based on '\n'. After splitting, i want to populate the split message into chunks of 1000 for processing. Is there any way of doing this without using iterator or loops ?
Also can we use something as sequence size ? below is the format used

```
@InboundChannelAdaptor(channel = "x", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "20000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1")
```

// This Channel is used to fetch a file

```
@Splitter(inputChannel = "x")
```

//Here I want to Split the message into chunks using FileSplitter
//fileSplitter.setOutputChannelName("y")

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "y")
```

//Logic to process chunks

**UPDATE** ----------Implementation-----------

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File(INBOUND_PATH));
    source.setFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    return source;
}

@Splitter(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
@Bean
public FileSplitter fileSplitter() {
   FileSplitter fileSplitter = new FileSplitter();
   fileSplitter.setOutputChannelName("chunkingChannel");
   return fileSplitter;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "chunkingChannel")
@Bean
public AggregatingMessageHandler chunker() {
    AggregatingMessageHandler aggregator = new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor());
    aggregator.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(1000));
    aggregator.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
    aggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(100L));
    aggregator.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
    aggregator.setOutputChannelName("processFileChannel");
    return aggregator;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processFileChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            List<String> strings = (List<String>) message.getPayload();
            System.out.println( "List Size :  "+ strings.size() + " for List " + strings.toString());
        }

    };
}
```

error i got while using AggregatorFactoryBean

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datastreamApplication': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chunker': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetObject must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.integration.datastream.DatastreamApplication.main(DatastreamApplication.java:37) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'chunker': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetObject must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.resolveTargetBeanFromMethodWithBeanAnnotation(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:449) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$0(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: targetObject must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:353) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageListProcessor.java:60) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageGroupProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean.createHandler(AggregatorFactoryBean.java:176) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AggregatorFactoryBean.createHandler(AggregatorFactoryBean.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:185) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:173) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:58) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, that's why people already down-voted it. Would be great to provide us much info as possible. For example I believe you have there some kind of `filter` to check a length of the line and you also try to do something with an `aggregator`. That's where you struggle with the mentioned `sequence size`.

I think your idea is correct and you still should continue to use a `FileSplitter`, but with slightly improved configuration. First of all we really might not be able to know an original size of file. On the other hand you can't know in advance how many lines you are going to filter.

For such a task the `FileSplitter` suggests `markers` option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/files.html#file-splitter

The first message before reading file is going to be with the `payload` `FileSplitter.FileMarker` and the `Mark.START`. The last one, when we are done reading file is a `Mark.END`. I would suggest to have a router (`PayloadTypeRouter`) just before filter for the line length to router `String` payloads into the filter for the line length and then to an aggregator. Those `FileSplitter.FileMarker` messages should go to some other branch of the router to filter a `Mark.START` message, because we are not interested in it for this scenario. The `Mark.END` should go to the mentioned aggregator and exactly this one should be treated as a `RealeaseStrategy` to complete a group of those lines. The `FileSplitter.FileMarker` message can be skipped from the files grouping function to emit only a `List<String>` you are interested in.

You can find more info in the relevant JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4116

**UPDATE**

Since you task is slightly different it is really disappointing that you didn't explain the problem properly in the beginning...

For the current task I would still stick with the `FileSplitter`:

```
@Splitter(inputChannel = "x")
@Bean
public FileSplitter fileSplitter() {
   FileSplitter fileSplitter = new FileSplitter();
   fileSplitter.setOutputChannelName("chunkingChannel");
   return fileSplitter;
}
```

And would use an `aggregator` with a simple `MessageCountReleaseStrategy(1000)` and `groupTimeout` for the last chunk `< 1000`:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "chunkingChannel")
@Bean
public AggregatorFactoryBean chunker() {
    AggregatorFactoryBean aggregator = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
    aggregator.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(1000));
    aggregator.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
    aggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(100L));
    aggregator.setOutputChannelName("y");
    aggregator.setProcessorBean(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor());
    return aggregator;
}
```

Comment: Hey Artem, first of all thanks for the answer but this is not something that i am looking, maybe my other question let you answer this was, anyway I have modified my queries see if you can help me out. Thank you

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hey Artem, thanks for the quick response. I used your approach and I was getting error : Bean creation error for the bean name chunker ( Target Object cannot be null). So I used AggregateMessageHandler instead of AggregatorFactoryBean and error got resolved and spilt worked. The only issue I faced is with the last chunk having size < 1000 which is getting group time out, so I added sendPartialResultOnExpiry as true which fetched the last group having size < 1000.

Comment: Glad to see that you have figured out everything by yourself! Time to accept an answer. Also I would like to see the whole stack trace about error: maybe we need to fix something back in the Framework

Comment: Previously, I tried to access only one directory. Now I'm trying to implement below scenario:
I have a trigger file and a data file which is kept in different directories.
Only if I receive a trigger file, I should be able to access the data file, then do the splitting and further processing logic.
Also, the case is there will be a single trigger file but multiple data files.  So after fetching the trigger file, I should be able to process all the data files.

Comment: Hey @artem can you help on above query or guide me please. thanks

Comment: I’ve seen your another SO question. Will answer when weekend is over

Comment: hey @ArtemBilan can you guide me a little.. i tried few things but still i am stuck. once again i need your help

Comment: What is the problem so far? You need to use an `AggregatorFactoryBean` and inject the mentioned in your config `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor` into the `setProcessorBean()` there. I've edited my answer on the matter.

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231415/how-can-i-read-files-from-two-different-directory-using-inboundchanneladapter).. i am trying to implement this updated scenario.. so far i can process only data directory.. but when the trigger concept comes i am confused. how to process multiple data file with only one trigger using SI ?

Comment: Looks like Gary takes care about you there

Comment: true..  but i didn’t understand.. if some references is provided that would be a lot of help.. also m new to SI.

Comment: So, ask such a question there in that your SO thread. It would better that one of us do one job, but not both. Otherwise we are not going to be efficient team.